# strtok()function which does not modify the original string, and should create a new string for the tokens to be returned

Tags: c, constants, c-strings, strtok, function-definition

I am trying to implement own strtok function but here i noticed that it changes the orginal string.I want to implement it in such a way it should create a new string for the tokens to be returned and it does not modify the original string.
Although i implemented this in main function but it should be handled in strtok function in itself.

My code is given below:

```
char *my_strtok(char * s2, char * delimit);//function prototyping
int main()
{
   char arr1[50]={"abc-efgh-ijkl-mnopq"}; 
   char buffer[50];
   sprintf(buffer,"%s",arr1);//for retaining the original string
   char *split  = my_strtok(arr1,"-");
   
   while(split != NULL)
   {
       printf("%s\t",split);
       split=my_strtok(NULL,"-");
       
   }
   
   return 0;
}
char *my_strtok(char * s2, char * delimit)
{
   int j=0;
   static int curr;
   static char* s;
   int start=curr;
   if(s2 != NULL)
   {
       s=s2;
   }
   while(s[curr]!='\0')
   {
       j=0;
       while(delimit[j]!='\0')
       {
           if(s[curr]==delimit[j])//comparing the delimiter in the string
           {
               s[curr]='\0';//replaces the delimiter by delimiter
               curr=curr+1;//increment the curr position by 1
               if(s[start]!='\0')//here start=0 returns characters till encounters '\0'
               {
                  return (&s[start]);
                  
               }
               else
               {
                 start=curr;//Move to the next string after the delimiter
                 
               }
           }
        j++;   
       }
     curr++;  
   }
       
       
   s[curr] = '\0';
   if(s[start] == '\0')
       return NULL;
   else
       return &s[start];
}
```

Comment: You need to use `malloc()` to allocate new strings.

Comment: @sanchi gupta This statement  s[curr]='\0' changes the original string.

Comment: If your implementation does not modify the original string, the arguments should be of type `const char *`.

Comment: This simplest mechanism is to use `strdup()` and work on the duplicate: `char *dup = strdup(arr1); char *data = dup;` and then run the regular `strtok()` on `data` the first time you invoke it.  When you're finished, use `free(dup);`.  If you don't modify `dup`, you can do without the extra `data` variable.   YMMV.  Otherwise, coordination tends to be a problem.  Each separate token can be handled as a separate memory allocation — using your own variant of `strtok()`.  The [`strndup()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strndup.html) function might be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to implement it in such a way it should create a new string for
> the tokens to be returned and it does not modify the original string.

In this case the function parameters should be declared with the qualifier `const` like

```
char * my_strtok( const char *s2, const char *delimit );
```

After this if statement

```
if(s2 != NULL)
{
    s=s2;
}
```

the both pointers `s` and `s2` point to the same string. So statements like this

```
s[curr]='\0';
```

change the original character array.

You need to allocate dynamically an array for storing a sub-string. And in main you need to remember to free the dynamically allocated array when it is not required any more.

The function can be defined for example the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * my_strtok( const char *s, const char *delimit )
{
    static const char *p;

    if ( ( s == NULL ) && (  p == NULL ||  *p == '\0' ) )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if ( s )
    {
        p = s;
    }

    p += strspn( p, delimit );

    if ( *p == '\0' )
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    const char *start = p;

    p += strcspn( p, delimit );

    size_t n = p - start;

    char *substr = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( substr )
    {
        substr[n] = '\0';
        memcpy( substr, start, n );
    }

    return substr;                      
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "abc-efgh-ijkl-mnopq";

    char *p = my_strtok( s, "-" );

    while ( p != NULL )
    {
        puts( p );
        free( p );
        p = my_strtok( NULL, "-" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
abc
efgh
ijkl
mnopq
```